Counting Excel timestamps if between to times, but time value different between timestamps and interval ranges
I have a list of timestamped events, and I'm using this formula to count the number of records present in each 15-minute interval:
=COUNTIFS('1 Raw'!$B:$B,">="&$B8,'1 Raw'!$B:$B,"<"&($B8+TIME(0,15,0)))

The timestamped events are on a sheet called "1 Raw" and in this case the time reference in B8 is 11:30 AM. This formula works perfectly UNLESS there is a timestamped event that occurs exactly at the upper bound (in this case, at 11:45:00 AM). Even though I'm using "<" and not "<=", the result includes the timestamped event at 11:45 AM in the total.
I copied/pasted the time values of the timestamped event and the time value of the upper bound, and the last digit is the culprit - how can that be the case?
Time value - timestamped event at 11:45:00.00 AM: 0.489583333333333
Time value - (B8+TIME(0,15,0):                    0.489583333333334

The current formula give the correct overall total, it just reports timestamped events that fall exactly on the upper bound in the wrong interval. I tried altering the formula for the upper bound to be "<="&($B8+TIME(0,14,59) but that excludes values and doesn't yield the correct overall total.
I also tried pasting in the times as time values and reporting them all the way up to milliseconds, with no luck.

Consider rounding the value in B8 before evaluating it =ROUND(B8,14)

Could you share some relevant sample data using this Table to Markdown Generator so we have something to work with? Simply copy not more than 21 relevant rows (including the headers) of a table into the website's text box, press Submit, press Copy and paste it into your post (question). Also, clearly state what is the expected result.

If you have MS365, visit this link to see how I rounded the values and used XMATCH with the 3rd argument set to -1 to get the boundaries correctly e.g. an interval between 11:30:00 and 11:44:59 both inclusive (considering your case). I don't understand what's happening here but maybe you should consider using ...+TIME(0,14,59).

Now that you've determined the value, is there a concern with saying "<"&0.489583333333333?  Using the fractions of 24 hours rather than the displayed time?

Thank you so much for the tips! After tweaking the formula based on the advice here and doing further quality control on the results, I'm sticking with the original formula. The mis-assigning of the timestamped record to the incorrect bin doesn't happen every time a timestamp occurs at exactly the upper bound - very, very odd. It's only happening on that single record out of a set of tens of thousands, so I'll just live with it.

The best way to compare timestamps is to express them by integer numbers of seconds (or other precision as required). Multiple a timestamp by 86400 to get seconds. Apply Excel's FLOOR(x,1) function or VBA Int to cut parts of a second if present.
FLOOR(0.489583333333333 * 86400,1) = 42300
FLOOR(0.489583333333334 * 86400,1) = 42300

In fact, Excel is somehow improved to get the correct result without flooring:
0.489583333333333 * 86400 = 42300
0.489583333333334 * 86400 = 42300

A8=TIME(11,30,0)
B8=A8*86400
A9=A8+TIME(0,15,0)
B9=A9*86400
=SUM(('1 Raw'!$B:$B*86400>=$B$8)*('1 Raw'!$B:$B*86400<$B$9))

COUNTIFS is replaced by SUM since the first one doesn't support the dynamic arrays.

You can mark the answer as accepted if it helps
